# Programatically get screen coordinates of selected element in Finder for Python or Swift

Tags: python, swift, macos, finder

I am trying to create a tool that will allow to do right click on Finder items while navigating with the keyboard.

The problem that I am having right now is finding a way to programatically find where the element that is selected is located on the screen. I would like to get the coordinates or any other way to know the position in the screen either on Python or Swift.

Comment: Does the accessibility inspector show coordinates and/or a Show Menu action?

Comment: Yes, it actually shows both of them when I select an item in Finder

Comment: Have you tried the Accessibility API to get the coordinates or the show the menu?

Comment: I am not that familiar with the Accessibility API or MacOS development in general. I took a quick glance into it, but wasn´t able to find anything so far

Comment: Seconding the accessibility API approach. You can make a system work where a script emulates a mouse pointer and clicks around on particular coordinates, but it's much more low fidelity, clunky, and unreliable. MacOS already has fantastic accessibility APIs (and the first party apps use them very well) which let you navigate the UI realllllly well.